# Compile Java 1.5 web app in Netbeans on Mac OSX 10.7.5

Tags: java, macos, netbeans

I am running Netbeans on my Mac OSX 10.7.5 which uses Java 1.6.  I need to compile my web app in Netbeans against Java 1.5.  I tried to install Java 1.5 on my Mac OSX, but it will not let you.  How can I compile my netbeans web app against Java 1.5 on my mac osx?

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Tools** -> **Java Platforms**. There, click on **Add Platform**, point it to **YOUR_JDK_LOCATION**. You can either set the another JDK version or remove existing versions.

after adding multiple platform change your project compile specification according to your requirement

To download jdk binary please visit below location

[Link 1 zip file](http://ituploads.com/software-downloads/apple/jdk.1.5.0-leopard.zip)

[Link 2 tar file](http://ituploads.com/software-downloads/apple/java.1.5.0-leopard.tar.gz)

Comment: I only see JDK 1.6 under Platforms.  I tried to install 1.5 on my mac osx, but it won't let me.

Comment: What are the exception you are geeting when you try to install jdk 5. if installation is not possible try to get binary zipped version from oracle and extract the same.

Comment: I cannot find a download on the oracle site for java 1.5 for mac.  Do you know exactly where I can find it?

Comment: Well I am an windows user don't know more about mac but let me search and find a download link for mac.

Comment: I take help one of my friend he send me that links

Comment: Where do I exactly put this extracted folder named '1.5.0'??

Comment: put any where but remember the path that will be required when you will go for adding platform in netbeans.

Comment: When I try to add the platform in Netbeans I get this error: "Cannot detect and install the selected platform. The java or javac may not be executable."

Answer (score 0):

change your java version

`$ export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v '1.5*'`

OR

parameterize the compiler like `javac -source 1.5 -target 1.5`

Comment: How would you do this is NetBeans?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I figured it out.  In Netbeans, if you right click your project and go to 'Properties', in the 'Sources' category there is an option that says 'Source/Binary Format' which contains a drop down list where you can select the JDK version to build your project.

Since I am running JDK 6 on my mac, it will allow you to select version 6 and below, and in my case, I select version 5.

Comment: Please note that this does not change the web-app version in the web.xml